# Scanf and a manual function to get string when they work together

Tags: c, scanf

I have a trouble with scanf and a manual function to get string in the input.

Here is my manual function to get a line of string in input (I also get the [nl] character):

```
void getln(char *a) {
    int i,c;
    i=0;
    do {
        c=getchar();
        a[i]=(char)c;
        i++;
    } while(c!='\n');
}
```

Then, I using it like this (char hs.school[40]; char hs.pc[20]; int hs.age;):

```
printf("Import age: ");
scanf("%d",&hs.age);
printf("Import personal code: ");
getln(hs.pc);
printf("Import school: ");
getln(hs.school);
```

The output:

```
Import age: 18
Import personal code: Import school: Vo Thi Sau
```

Why the *getln* call right after *scanf* call is ignored? (But the next *getln* works well)
Can you explain me the details and suggest me how to fix this bug. Thanks!

Edited:
Here is my full code that *take the user inputs and export that inputs back to the screen*, which is run well after I did a little trick, but I decide to make a question, mainly for expanding my knowlegde ^_^ Thanks for your answers.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void getln(char *);
void putstr(char *);

int main(void) {
    struct Student {
        struct Fullname {
            char first[10],middle[20],last[10];
        }fu;
        struct Native {
            char social[30],district[30],province[30];
        }na;
        struct Score {
            double maths,physics,chemistry;
        }sc;
        char pc[20],school[40];
        int age;
    }hs;
    printf("Import stage:\n");
    printf("- Import full name:\n");
    printf("++ First name: ");
    getln(hs.fu.first);
    printf("++ Middle name: ");
    getln(hs.fu.middle);
    printf("++ Last name: ");
    getln(hs.fu.last);
    printf("- Import native living place:\n");
    printf("++ Social: ");
    getln(hs.na.social);
    printf("++ District: ");
    getln(hs.na.district);
    printf("++ Province: ");
    getln(hs.na.province);
    printf("- Import school: ");
    getln(hs.school);
    printf("- Import personal code: "); // I have done a little trick
    getln(hs.pc);                       // before I post the question,
    printf("- Import age: ");           // which swaped these two stage,
    scanf("%d",&hs.age);                // but it's works like a charm ^_^
    printf("- Import scores:\n");
    printf("++ Mathematics: ");
    scanf("%lf",&hs.sc.maths);
    printf("++ Physics: ");
    scanf("%lf",&hs.sc.physics);
    printf("++ Chemistry: ");
    scanf("%lf",&hs.sc.chemistry);
    printf("\nExport stage:\n");
    printf("- Full name: ");
    putstr(hs.fu.first);
    printf(" ");
    putstr(hs.fu.middle);
    printf(" ");
    putstr(hs.fu.last);
    printf(".\n");
    printf("- Native living place: ");
    putstr(hs.na.social);
    printf(", ");
    putstr(hs.na.district);
    printf(", ");
    putstr(hs.na.province);
    printf(".\n");
    printf("- School: ");
    putstr(hs.school);
    printf(".\n");
    printf("- Personal code: ");
    putstr(hs.pc);
    printf(".\n");
    printf("- Age: %d.\n",hs.age);
    printf("- Scores (Mathematics, Physics, Chemistry): %.2lf, %.2lf, %.2lf.\n",hs.sc.maths,hs.sc.physics,hs.sc.chemistry);
    return 0;
}

void getln(char *a) {
    int i,c;
    i=0;
    do {
        c=getchar();
        a[i]=(char)c;
        i++;
    } while(c!='\n');
}
void putstr(char *a) {
    int i;
    i=0;
    while(a[i]!='\n') {
        putchar(a[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the remainder of your code? Please see: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Thank David for your advise, I have thought my posted code is Minimal, but I will edit the post and add the full code.

Comment: Thank you, that helps.  Take a look at my improvements to the `getln` function in the answer below. It will save you from writing past the end of your array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you explain me the details ...

I'll try not to use confusing terms such as *buffer*.

You probably already know that `"%d"` corresponds to a set of decimal digit characters which get transformed into an `int`. When you press 'Enter' as others have suggested, the `'\n'` character is transmitted via `stdin`. `'\n'` isn't a decimal digit character, so it gets placed back onto the stream for your `getln` function to discover later on...

In reality, your "getln call right after scanf call" *probably* isn't ignored; it's *probably* just reading the trailing `'\n'` and seeing an empty line.

That is assuming the other problem isn't coming into play. `getln` can't see how many bytes `a` points to, so it can't tell when it's about to overflow, and hence makes no attempt to prevent buffer overflows... You've basically rewritten `gets`. If your input is lengthy enough, then I suppose this could also cause your problem... A buffer overflow is undefined behaviour, and the consequences of using undefined behaviour are *undefined*.

On the topic of undefined behaviour, since `getln` isn't technically producing a string, I do hope you're not using it as input for a standard string function later on...

Also on the topic of undefined behaviour, what do you suppose might happen if the user enters something that isn't a set of decimal digits? `scanf` conveys input errors via the return value... so **never ignore the return value**. You can (and should, at some point) find more information about this in [the scanf manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html).

---

> ... and suggest me how to fix this bug.

It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to discard user input, but unfortunately you can't expect a solution that results in better user experience without blowing your code size (and this explanation) well out of proportion.

---

You can discard the remainder of the line (which is probably just a `'\n'`) following the set of decimal digits using `scanf` like so: `scanf("%*[^\n]"); getchar();`... Following the `"%d"` `scanf` call, of course... You could even merge the two together, like so:

```
if (scanf("%d%*[^\n]", &hs.age) != 1) {
    puts("ERROR: EOF or file access error.");
    exit(0);
}
getchar();
```

Unfortunately, if your user uses the spacebar key rather than enter, he or she probably won't find out about the problems with this until it's slightly too late...

---

As for the buffer overflow problem, I recommend using `fgets` rather than `gets`. `fgets` also has failure modes, which are conveyed via the return value and the contents of the array. The return value is used to convey `EOF` and file access errors, and the presense (or rather lack of) of a `'\n'` in the return value is used to convey when the input line was too large to store in the array. We can notify the user of the overflow (which I'm sure they'll appreciate) and discard the excess using the same `scanf` trick used earlier...

```
if (fgets(hs.pc, sizeof hs.pc, stdin) == NULL) {
    puts("ERROR: EOF or file access error.");
    exit(0);
}

size_t size = strcspn(hs.pc, "\n");
if (hs.pc[size] != '\n') {
    printf("WARNING: MAXIMUM SIZE OF %zu EXCEEDED! LINE TRUNCATED.\n", sizeof hs.pc - 1);
    scanf("%*[^\n]");
    getchar();
}

hs.pc[size] = '\0';
```

I suppose it would make sense to wrap these solutions into functions, except that the functions would then promote the discarding of user input. Nonetheless, the later one is lengthy enough that you'd most likely benefit from abstraction...

```
void getln(char *a, size_t a_size) {
    if (fgets(a, a_size, stdin) == NULL) {
        puts("ERROR: EOF or file access error.");
        exit(0);
    }

    size_t size = strcspn(a, "\n");
    if (a[size] != '\n') {
        printf("WARNING: MAXIMUM SIZE OF %zu EXCEEDED! LINE TRUNCATED.\n", a_size - 1);
        scanf("%*[^\n]");
        getchar();
    }

    a[size] = '\0';
}
```

... and now you can use that like so: `getln(hs.pc, sizeof hs.pc);`

Answer (score 1):

You are not clearing the input buffer. So in this newline will be placed after the first input given to `scanf`. So `getchar` will get the new line as a input. So loop will quit.

Use this line after the `scanf`.

```
int c;
if ( scanf("%d",&hs.age) != 1 ) { 
       printf("Invalid Input\n");retrun 0; }

while((c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF );
```

It will clear the input buffer. Then it will ask the second input from the user.

Answer (score 1):

After taking input **hs.age** you pressed in **Enter**, which is a **\n** character. So your getln() is called but the loop is broken just after one iteration as **c** contains **'\n'**. if you print **hs.pc**, there will be a new line in your output screen.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getln` call isn't skipped, it is taking the `newline` character left in `stdin` (the input buffer) as its input and it reads `'\n'` as `c`, assigns it to `a[i]`, checks whether `c` is a `'\n'` char and exits.

To solve the initial problem, you need to clear the input buffer before calling `getln`. You can either do that with the `while` loop as suggested in the other answer, or you can craft a proper format string for `scanf` that will consume the newline, emptying the buffer. (not foolproof), but an alternative `scanf` would be:

```
scanf(" %d%*c",&hs.age);
```

Which would skip all whitespace before the number (including any newlines), read the decimal value, and then read and discard the newline. **Note:** this only works for a number without trailing characters. Entering `13abc` would leave `bc\n` in `stdin`. The while loop in this case is more flexible as it reads all characters until a newline is encountered and is probably the better choice:

```
scanf(" %d",&hs.age);
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

As for your `getln` function, it only needs to read each character into `a[i]`. There isn't a real need for `c`. You will also want the same checks on your input so that no newline is left. You will also want to check `i` against the maximum lengths of `a` minus 1. I would suggest a `#define MAXS 128` for the maximum string length for your input. That would allow something to test `i` against to prevent writing beyond the end of your string.

Here is an alternative to your `getln`. **Note**: it is type `int` allowing it to return the length of the line read so you can determine what to do if it has reached `MAXS` (as there will still be characters in `stdin` at that point). As a general rule, if you are doing something in a function when there is a potential for error, it is better to return a value indicating success/failure/problem:

```
#define MAXS 128
...
int getln (char *a) 
{
    size_t i = 0;
    while ((a[i] = getchar()) != '\n' && a[i] != EOF)
    {
        i++;
        if (i == MAXS - 1)
        {
            a[i] = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    return i;
}
```